# C program not able to execute a system call after initialising all the elements of huge array to some constant

Tags: c

In this sample C program:

```
 main()
    {
       //initialise a huge array (size close to 80GB)
       int **a;
       a=(int **)calloc(140000,sizeof(int *));
       for(int i=0;i<140000;i++)
         a[i]=(int *)calloc(140000,sizeof(int));

      //Now initialise all the elements to 1
      for(i=0;i<140000;i++)
      for(j=0;j<140000;j++)
        a[i][j]=1;

     //Now if I do this:
      system("bash dummy.sh");
   }
```

Here dummy.sh is not running after I'm initializing all the array elements to 1.

But if I do this:

```
        main()
        {
           //initialise a huge array (size close to 80GB)
           int **a;
           a=(int **)calloc(140000,sizeof(int *));
           for(int i=0;i<140000;i++)
             a[i]=(int *)calloc(140000,sizeof(int));
          //Now if I do this:
          system("bash dummy.sh");
          //Now initialise all the elements to 1
          for(i=0;i<140000;i++)
          for(j=0;j<140000;j++)
            a[i][j]=1;

         }
```

In the first scenario the 'C' program is simply exiting without calling system call but in the second scenario it is working as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

NOTE:
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS with 4.4.0 linux kernel version.
My system has 128GiB of DRAM.

Comment: `for(i=0 - 140000)` Are you telling us that is valid C syntax on your compiler?

Comment: You should be learning to code 21st Century C — not archaic 20th Century C.  Using plain `main()` is very old C; it was made non-standard by C99.  If you're using Turbo C, then be aware that you are using an antique compiler.

Comment: Syntactically it is valid. But not in any other interpretation.

Comment: I apologize for posting it like that. I edited the code now. That was not my point. I did not get any compile time error nor a run time error. But I'm unable to figure out the behavior. Thanks

Comment: Please make the title more descriptive of the problem. As written, somebody with a similar problem will not be able to find this question because the title is so vague.

Comment: Presumably you're on a 64-bit machine.  You're attempting to allocate close to 80 GiB of memory, and you've not checked that any (let alone all) of the allocations succeeded.  Gut feel: your o/s per-process limits don't let you use 80 GiB of memory.  Also, your system may not have enough memory to allow you to fork a second process which is a copy of your first (though copy-on-write technology should limit the amount that has to be copied).  Also, what platform are you on?  Windows, Unix, Linux, Mac, something else?

Comment: And enable compiler warnings. All of them.

Comment: I think @JonathanLeffler hit the nail on the head. I would second his guess your allocation exceed the process limits set by the system... Another good reason why you would only notice this after attempting to write to the memory would be "optimistic allocation", where the system always returns a valid pointer even if no available memory was allocated (Linux does that). If the allocation was optimistic, than the OS will only raise the segmentation / page fault signal once your application attempted to write to the memory.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS with 4.4.0 linux kernel version.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger and see where it exits and why.

Comment: You should check the return value of `calloc` -- especially so when allocating large amounts that may exhaust available memory.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that the OS uses lazy allocation, and so the loop of writing `1`'s causes the OS to terminate the process.  So, you see the system call happen only if you do it before the loop.

Comment: Are you sure your program *gets* to the `system` call?

Answer (score 1):

From the manual.

> The  system()  library  function uses fork(2) to create a child process
>          that executes the shell command specified in command using execl(3)  as
>          follows:

`execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);`

I think your parent process is getting terminated before the execution of the child process.So, call `execl()` directly.

```
execl("/bin/bash","bash","path_to_dummy.sh",NULL);
```

Or, if you really need a child process to execute it :

```
pid_t id = fork();
if(id > 0) {
    /**
     * In parent
     */
    wait(NULL);
}else if(id == 0) {
    /**
     * In Child
     */
    execl("/bin/bash","bash","path_to_dummy.sh",NULL);
}
```

Comment: That should explain it. 128GB of RAM is not enough to fork a process that takes 80GB of space.

Answer (score 0):

If a `calloc()` fails and returns `NULL`, `system()` will still work on the second sample because you are not attempting to overwrite memory you are not supposed to touch before calling it.

On the first code, some `calloc()` call is failing and returning `NULL` and you are not handling this problem correctly, you write to `NULL` and the program crashes before you call `system()`.